# Cannot call a class as a function scala.js

Tags: scala.js

```
 val ListDataSource = ReactNative.ListView.asInstanceOf[js.Dynamic].DataSource
    js.Dynamic.newInstance(ListDataSource)(args).asInstanceOf[ListViewDataSource[T]]
```

this code is working fine in react-native 0.5.0 ,but when i upgraded to 0.6 i am getting following error

`Cannot call a class as a function`

in js land nothing changed!

```
dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }),
```

Edit : ok i lied , there is a change in jsworld ,react-native  using babel in 0.6 instead of jstransform .

```
function _classCallCheck(instance,Constructor){
    if(!(instance instanceof Constructor)){throw new TypeError('Cannot call a class as a function');
    }}
function ListViewDataSource(params){_classCallCheck(this,ListViewDataSource);
```

https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/798

Comment: did you try calling  var ds = new ListView.DataSource? As in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html

Comment: thanks for reply ,but its fixed in scala.js now via @ScalaJSDefined :)

Comment: Please consider answering your question in this case. :)